# Svelte input bind JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, svelte

I followed [this](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/group-inputs) svelte tutorial and I wonder if I could do this group binding to a JSON array instead of simple array, for example I would like to do a planets selector:

```
    <script>
        let planets = [{
                name: 'Jupiter',
                enable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Saturn',
                enable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Uran',
                enable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Neptun',
                enable: false
            },
            {
                name: 'Pluto',
                enable: true
            },
        ];

        $: planets, console.log(planets)
    </script>

    {#each planets as planet}
        <label>
            <input type=checkbox bind:group={planets} name={planet.name} value={planet}>
            {planet.name}
        </label>
    {/each}
```

[This](https://svelte.dev/repl/0e7757e403c8400da7371a157d7a37e2?version=3.20.1) is a REPL. I wonder if there is a way how to properly bind JSON array (enable array field with inputs value) in svelte each loop. Now it pops out with each item as you click as you can see in REPL's console.log and I would like just to uncheck it.

With bind:checked property displays proper way

```
<input type=checkbox bind:checked={planet.enable} value={planet}>
```

But this does not change array.enable value on click. Can I achieve responsibility of planets array here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set the value to planet. When you remove this and only use the checked property, then the array updates with the proper value.

```
<script>
    let planets = [{
            name: 'Jupiter',
            enable: false,
        },
        {
            name: 'Saturn',
            enable: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Uran',
            enable: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Neptun',
            enable: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Pluto',
            enable: true
        },
    ];
        $: planets, console.log(planets)
</script>

{#each planets as planet}
    <label>
        <input type=checkbox bind:checked={planet.enable}>
        {planet.name}
    </label>
{/each}
```

You can checkout my [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/570853ca84cf4124a7744470e1bdb1a7?version=3.20.1).

Here is a screenshot from the update:
[image: Proof that the update worked]

Comment: thank you for response, however if I use checked property as you suggest, it still does not mutate planets array (the line $: planets, console... outputs still the original array over and over)

Comment: Are you sure? For me it outputs the array with the enable property changed.

https://svelte.dev/repl/570853ca84cf4124a7744470e1bdb1a7?version=3.20.1

Comment: If I enable all checks it shows me in the console log:

Array(5)[
▶
 0: Object { name: "Jupiter" ,enable: false }
▶
 1: Object { name: "Saturn" ,enable: false }
▶
 2: Object { name: "Uran" ,enable: false }
▶
 3: Object { name: "Neptun" ,enable: false }
▶
 4: Object { name: "Pluto" ,enable: true }
length: 5
]

the only one enabled are the default ones (Pluto in this case)

I would also expect to be reactive this way, but I cant see it :)

Comment: When you check another one, the enable property changes to true.I updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was checking REPL console's log and totally forgot the browser's one. It just looks like, that REPL console cannot catch the change yet.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. To be honest, I didn't even see that console. It is strange that the object does not get updated, maybe that is a bug in their console.

Comment: It is a bug in svelte REPL console as described in https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-repl/issues/80 - be aware those, that are not relying on browser's console log